# SASS conditional for global override

Tags: sass

I am trying to implement an idea where I can individually set a bottom border for heading tags (h1,h2,h3,h4), but also have a global override switch. 
Something like this:

```
$h1-border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
$h2-border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
$h3-border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
$h4-border: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
```

...but if I set something like:

```
$all-heading-borders: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
```

then it would **override/ignore** the individual settings and apply them to the h1-h4 tags in one hit.

What would I use for this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use the `!default` flag and set all of your variables equal to the "global" variable:

```
// overrides can be done at any point *before* you reference them in your code
$h1-border: 2px dotted orange;

// default configuration variables
$all-heading-borders: 4px solid #CCCCCC !default;

$h1-border: $all-heading-borders !default;
$h2-border: $all-heading-borders !default;
$h3-border: $all-heading-borders !default;
$h4-border: $all-heading-borders !default;

// oh look, another override
$h2-border: 1px solid grey;

h1 {
    border: $h1-border;
    outline: $h3-border;
}

h2 {
    border: $h2-border;
    outline: $h4-border;
}
```

Output:

```
h1 {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
  outline: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
}

h2 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  outline: 4px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon, I think I was over-complicating it with mixins and if statements, as you can guess I am new to Sass.